# close new open window when clicked on print button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm using this function to print the content of a specific div

```
 print() {
  let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1080,height=595');
  var htmlToPrint = '' +
  '<style type="text/css">' +
  'table th, table td {' +
  'border:1px solid #000;' +
  'padding;0.5em;' +
  '}' +
  '</style>';

  popupWin.document.open();
 
  let printContents = this.Page.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  htmlToPrint += printContents;
  let printHead = document.head.innerHTML;
  popupWin.document
    .write(`<html>
       ${printHead}
      <body onload="window.print();">${htmlToPrint}</body></html>`);
  popupWin.document.close();

}
```

but the issue here is there are one window open and above that another print dialog gets open when i close the print dialog print window is still open i want to close the new opened winsow as soon as clicked on print or cancel button.

Comment: Instead of opening the window as a popup, what most do is create a hidden iFrame instead, call print on this.

Answer (score 0):

Embed this before all (right after `<html>` of `popupWin`:

```js
window.onafterprint = () => window.close()
```

> **Note**: that the `afterprint` event of `window` will be called as soon as the print popup closes regardless of whether the user prints successfully or fails or presses cancel

Comment: I tried it in angular but it is not working